# Will itext 2.1.7 version pdf support XMLWorker for converting the html to pdf?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using iText lowagie 2.1.7 version for generating the PDF from HTML file. I have used xmlworker:5.5.3 but not supported with  lowagie 2.1.7 version. The error message shown is

> No signature of method: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml() is applicable for argument types: (com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.lowagie.text.Document, java.io.InputStreamReader) values: [com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter@331801, com.lowagie.text.Document@1a6ce9c1, ...] Possible solutions: parseXHtml(com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementHandler, java.io.InputStream), parseXHtml(com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementHandler, java.io.Reader), parseXHtml(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document, java.io.InputStream), parseXHtml(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document, java.io.Reader)

What may be the solution for this. Or alternative to convert HTML to PDF using iText 2.1.7 version?

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTMLWorker in iText 2.1.7, as an alternative:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
...
Document document = new Document();
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("path/to/generatedfile.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader("<html>...</html>"));
document.close();
```

I expect that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

XML Worker 5.5.4 (and previous versions) will only work with the corresponding iText version. There is no way to use XML Worker with iText 2.1.7, nor will there ever be a way to do this. It wouldn't be a good investment to create an XML Worker add-on for iText 2.1.7 as iText 2.1.7 should no longer be used in business. This is explained in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially

That's a question that made it into the book ["The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow"](https://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) of which the first 17 pages were published a moment ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially. This link is taken down. Could you post it in some other space? @bruno